# Is there a official way to show asterisk for one label of two fields in Primefaces 6.1.1?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a field in form like this. Field **Capacity** have 2 inputs **hour** and **minute** and we require one of **hour** and **minute** input needs to be filled.

So is there any official way to make the label have the asterisk while this label is used for 2 inputs?

[Screenshot: Capacity field haves 2 inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNKOU.png)

```
<p:outputLabel for="[forWhat]" value="Capacity" />
<p:inputText id="hourInput" />
<p:inputText id="minuteInput" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you remove the post validate Event question

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje I mark it deleted because I already found the solution to make my expected field invoke to postvalidate event. I am doing like this: `<inputText><f:event listener="bean.validate" type="postValidate"></inputText>`

Comment: Than post that as an answer...  please undelete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a HTML label can only be used for one single HTML input field. If it cannot be done in HTML, it cannot be done in JSF.

See also:

- [Single label for two inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854062/single-label-for-two-inputs)

Comment: Composite component? https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html?

Comment: ... or a custom component, or a single field with a custom duration validator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I already implemented the custom validator for 2 inputs, is it possible to add the asterisk to the label without "for" attribute?

I know I can add the "*" character for the label manually or using css but I just try to make it follow the jsf way.

Comment: I'd go for a custom validator on one field.

Comment: @BKL: Does the `indicateRequired` help? Like mentioned in the docs?

Comment: @Kukeltje `indicateRequired` is used for `Displays * symbol if the input is required, default value is true.`, so it cannot help my case. I followed the way @JasperdeVries mentioned: create a custom validator to validate 2 inputs and set `for` attribute of label to `hourInput`.

Comment: Yes I know what it is used for... , check the other answer...

Answer (score 2):

`indicateRequired='true'` should always display the '*', also without a attached input.
The default value is 'auto', which checks if the attached input is marked as required.

Comment: hmmm so I **DID** read the documentation carefully and the comment by @bkl above is not correct.

Comment: Should you check again the document for outputLabel here: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/outputlabel ?

As I understand, it correct to say the default value is auto but it's just `Displays * symbol if the input is required.` only.


I also tried putting `indicateRequired='true'` for my label when the related input does not have the `required='true'`, the "*" does not appear in the label.

Comment: I also tried removing 'for' in the label to detach the input but it does not work too.

Comment: It should be exactly like i said: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/outputlabel/OutputLabelRenderer.java#L162

Comment: I see the different. Sorry for my bad, I did not care and mention about the primefaces version I am currently using. Actually `indicateRequired` cannot work for my case because I am using Primefaces 6.1.1: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_1/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/outputlabel/OutputLabelRenderer.java. You are right for version from 6.2.

Anyway, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Thank you @Kukeltje for your help!

Comment: Cheers, please add the version info to the question